# Magento 2 Sort Reviews by rating

Tags: collection, magento2.2, sorting, review

I want to add sorting in Review Listing. What is the logic to add Sort by ratings?

[image]

I have override method `getReviewsCollection()` of  `Magento/Review/Block/Product/View.php` So I have `$this->_reviewsCollection` on my hand.

Anyone has Idea how to apply sort on base of rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Solution as below:

```
$countColumn = new \Zend_Db_Expr("COUNT(*)");
$percentColumn = new \Zend_Db_Expr("SUM(percent)/".$countColumn );

$this->_reviewsCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
   ['rating_vote'=>$this->_reviewsCollection->getTable('rating_option_vote')],
   'rating_vote.review_id=main_table.review_id',
   ['sum' => 'SUM(percent)', 'count' => $countColumn, 'average' => $percentColumn]);

$this->_reviewsCollection->getSelect()->group('rating_vote.review_id');

$this->_reviewsCollection->getSelect()->order('average desc');
```

Comment: bro i have a similar problem but for backend, can you take a look?